# cant write varibles into php file using file_put_contents PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to edit a file using the `file_put_contents`

Everything works fine (the data shows up in the test.php, well most of it) but the variables do not.

heres an example of my problem

**code for the file that will perform the `file_put_contents`:**

```
<?php
 file_put_contents("test.php","<?

$title = "title_name_goes_here"
echo $title;

?>");
?>
```

**Code that shows up in the target file (`test.php`):**

```
<?

 = this_is_my_name
echo ;

?>
```

**What should show up in `test.php`:**

```
<?

    $title = "title_name_goes_here"
    echo $title;

    ?>
```

Also, I'm using Dreamweaver to write the code in and it seems to have problems (code errors) when i insert the quote for the `$title`'s value so its ok if i used `$title = title_name_goes_here` but it doesn't like `$title = "title_name_goes_here"`. When i say its okay, i mean dreamweaver doesn't show any code errors but it still doesn't do what it should.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the quotes (and the dollar signs):

```
<?php
 file_put_contents("test.php","<?

\$title = \"title_name_goes_here\"
echo \$title;

?>");
?>
```

If you don't want to see the ugly escapes just use single quotes:

```
<?php
 file_put_contents('test.php",'<?

$title = "title_name_goes_here"
echo $title;

?>');
?>
```

Comment: Or actually, just use single quotes all the time unless you need variable expansion. :)

Comment: You're a LEGEND! Worked like a charm! Thanks!